# Ruby & IMAP - Accessing Office 365 with Oauth 2.0

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, outlook, imap

So MS disabled IMAP for basic auth as we all know.

I am trying to figure out how to get the OAUTH 2.0 working using ruby (not ruby on rails).
I have Azure APP and everything needed (I think), but I can not find any code related to ruby and getting the access token.

First step is completed, but next step is to get the access token.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth

I need to read different Outlook mailboxes.

Could someone please explain how to do this?

Comment: Can you show some code for context?

Comment: @tadman see the answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SOLUTION** for me!

Steps I took.

1. Made an Azure app ('[Device Flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Device-Code-Flow)' was the easiest way to go for me) Check the Steps in the link. You also need to change some settings in your APP if you want to use IMAP. See the youtube link [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMYA-146dmM) between 2:50 - 4:30
2. Get the postman requests from this link (scroll down a little) ([click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow))
3. From postman you can use "`Device Flow`" requests.
4. Start with `Device Authorization Request` (you need a scope and client_id for this) I used `https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All` scope.
5. go to the link that you got back from the request and enter the required code.
6. now go to `Device Access Token Request` and use the "device_code" from the last request and put that under `code`, under body.
7. You should get an `access_token`

**Connect using ruby**

```
require 'gmail_xoauth' # MUST HAVE! otherwise XOAUTH2 auth wont work
require 'net/imap'
    imap = Net::IMAP.new(HOST, PORT, true)
    access_token = "XXXXX"
    user_name = "email@outlook.com"
    p imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2',"#{user_name}", "#{access_token}")

    # example
    imap.list('','*').each do |folders|
      p folders
    end
```

**XOAUTH2 Returns**

```
#<struct Net::IMAP::TaggedResponse tag="RUBY0001", name="OK", data=#<struct Net::IMAP::ResponseText code=nil, text="AUTHENTICATE completed.">, raw_data="RUBY0001 OK AUTHENTICATE completed.\r\n
```

**Just to specify**

```
HOST = 'outlook.office365.com'
PORT = 993
```

**UPDATE 25.01.2023**

```
class Oauth2
  require 'selenium-webdriver'
  require 'webdrivers'
  require 'net/http'

  # Use: Oauth2.new.get_access_code
  # Grants access to Office 365 emails.

  def get_access_code
    p "### Access Request Started #{Time.now} ###"
    begin
      codes = device_auth_request
      authorize_device_code(codes[:user_code])
      access_code = device_access_token(codes[:device_code])
      access_code
    rescue => e
      p e
      p "Something went wrong with authorizing"
    end
  end

  def device_auth_request # Returns user_code and device_code
    url = URI('https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode')

    https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    https.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
    request.body = "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&scope=%09https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2FIMAP.AccessAsUser.All"

    response = https.request(request)
    {
      user_code: JSON.parse(response.read_body)["user_code"],
      device_code: JSON.parse(response.read_body)["device_code"]
    }
  end

  def device_access_token(device_code)
    url = URI('https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token')

    https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    https.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
    request.body = "grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Adevice_code&code=#{device_code}&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"

    response = https.request(request)
    JSON.parse(response.read_body)["access_token"]
  end

  def authorize_device_code(device_code)
    # SELENIUM SETUP
    driver = setup_selenium
    driver.get "https://microsoft.com/devicelogin"
    sleep(4)
    # ------------------------------------------

    # Give Access
    element = driver.find_element(:class, "form-control")
    element.send_keys(device_code)
    sleep(2)
    element = driver.find_element(:id, "idSIButton9")
    element.submit
    sleep(2)
    element = driver.find_element(:id, "i0116")
    element.send_keys("YOUR OUTLOOK ACCOUNT EMAIL")
    sleep(2)
    element = driver.find_element(:class, "button_primary")
    element.click
    sleep(2)
    element = driver.find_element(:id, "i0118")
    element.send_keys("YOUR OUTLOOK PASSWORD")
    element = driver.find_element(:class, "button_primary")
    element.click
    sleep(2)
    element = driver.find_element(:class, "button_primary")
    element.click
    sleep(2)
    # ------------------------------------------
    driver.quit
  end

  def setup_selenium
    require 'selenium-webdriver'

    # set up Selenium
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new(
      prefs: {
        download: {
          prompt_for_download: false
        },
        plugins: {
          'always_open_pdf_externally' => true
        }
      }
    )
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    # options.add_argument('-incognito')
    options.add_argument('disable-popup-blocking')
    Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
  end
end
```

Comment: How do you manage token refresh? Moreover, the token endpoint does not return the refresh_token to me, did I miss a setting? Thnx

Comment: @IwanB. I do not use token refresh, I just make a new access_token every time I need one (I have the steps automated). Starting with the step 4 and in the step 5 I use selenium gem to automate the process, it automatically goes to the link and logs in with my user. I will update my answer above.

Comment: Hi Brandon, thank you very much for the answer and for the update. In the meantime I have found the solution to get the refresh_token: you have to change the scope to "https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All offline_access" (simply add offline_access).

Comment: Does this still work? We try to use the connection token with the net/imap library but we only get failed authentication errors?

Comment: @BvuRVKyUVlViVIc7 Authentication errors probably relate to permissions on your account. See step 1 Youtube link and also allow your user to use IMAP or whatever protocol you are using.