# Sending Email with Ruby on Rails and OAuth2 (Office 365)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, office365

Our application is built on

- ruby 2.2.1p85
- Rails 4.2.5

We use ActionMailer to send notification emails. My old code that rely on ActionMailer and SMTP is:

```
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.office365.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "smtp.office365.com",
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => "MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS",
    :password => "MY_PASSWORD",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  ......

  def general_mail (to, subject, content, attachmts = [] )
    attachmts.each do |attachment|
        attachments[File.basename(attachment)] = File.read(attachment, mode: 'rb')
    end
    
    mail(to: to, subject: subject) do |format|
        format.text { render :text => content }
    end
  end
```

The code now is not working because the old authentication method will be deprecated and switch to OAuth2.

Can someone help me to make the notification email code work again under Oauth2?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I searched online, didn't find much documentation on how mailer works with Oauth2

Comment: I found this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74178121/ruby-imap-accessing-office-365-with-oauth-2-0) that might be helpful

Comment: along with the previous comment, here goes how to [possible implement on rails settings](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/199a76bed3fc518508b46135691914a1cfd8bff8/lib/mail/network/retriever_methods/imap.rb#L176). As far I could notice, you will have to switch from smtp to imap, to use `authentication: "XOAUTH2"` on your settings